# video overlay on another video with rounded corner, transparency, opacity, scaling, and border all together with FFMPEG in PHP

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to change a video with Rotation, rounded corner,  transparent, scaling, and border all with together and overlay on a video;
I am trying to do this with FFMPEG in PHP but getting issue in transparent background; I am getting green background please help;

```
ffmpeg -i empt_vid_5891581054410.mp4 -i merged-571580302534.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=-    30*PI/180:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih):c=none [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10:enable='between(t,2,7)', colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5" -auto-alt-ref 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy overlayavatar.mp4
```

Comment: See current output:  https://nimb.ws/qpaf08

Answer (score 0):

Add `format=yuva444p,` before 'rotate'.

```
ffmpeg -i empt_vid_5891581054410.mp4\
-i merged-571580302534.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva444p,rotate=-30*PI/180:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih):c=none [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10:enable='between(t,2,7)', colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5" -auto-alt-ref 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy overlayavatar.mp4
```